# How many is a zillion?

Tags: word-usage, numbers

1 million = 1,000,000.

1 billion = 1,000,000,000 or 1,000,000,000,000 depending on if using the [long or short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales).

How many is a zillion?

Although Wikipedia redirects "Zillion" to "[Indefinite and Fictitious Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_and_fictitious_numbers)," are there expert definitions or defining professional usages of the word?  The same article also describes how "forty" started out as an indefinite large number but now has a fairly precise meaning.

Comment: To all the down-and-close voters: Please remember this is a site about English Language **and usage.**

Comment: Is gazillion bigger than that!

Comment: To all the OPs present and future, please share your [research](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/zillion) and think about providing a little context.

Comment: On using a `z`-prefix to denote the "superlative", the "utmost": when I was a kid, I had kinda shaggy hair, and we were visiting grandma. For whatever reason the parents and grandparents had noticed my unkempt look that day, and were discussing it, and my mom said "The style among teens these days is to try to look like you slept on the [A train](http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/aline.htm)", to which my 80-something year old grandmother, who was born, lived, and died in rural CT immediately replied "Well, *he* looks like he slept on the Z train." (which, of course, does not exist).

Comment: @DanBron I think the "Z" in that context is not about superlative by itself, but by being the most distant/opposite from "A."

Comment: Yes, just as "billion" has a "b", and "z" is as "far down the alphabet" as you can go.

Comment: Yet apparently no one finds humor in the answer below, and a comment to @vickyace like "Yes, by a factor of ga" would likely be quite poorly received in this crowd.

Comment: @WBT Answers are typically not upvoted for *humor* but *correctness*. An answer may be funny, but wrong, and upvoting it would send the wrong message to future visitors, who may be (eg) non-native speakers and unable to distinguish a joke from an authoritative answer. In my experience on SE, jokes/puns/humor tend to be upvoted as comments, or as answers when posted on April 1st (though even then joke questions and answers tend to have short lives on SE, because "we hate fun").

Comment: @DanBron Then the answer should be upvoted for correctness as a expert usage of the word, as requested in the question.

Comment: @WBT But it's not an *expert use of the word*, it's a *jocular use of the word*, by *experts in aeronautical engineering*, not *English*. Disregarding anything else, in the face of any other arguments one may advance or wish to advance, a *zillion* means a large indefinite number (as WS2 demonstrates), and trying to pin it down to any precise quantity is *incorrect*, bottom line, and for the reason will likely be poorly received by speakers of English, on this site or off it.

Comment: When I want to know the precise meaning of a word, I would most strongly prefer to get that from the experts in whatever area that has most use for the term or most incentive to use the term carefully and accurately.  For example, I'd rather get a definition of "fairing" as used in that same context from an aeronautical engineer than an English major or [OED ("A present brought back from a fair")](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67719?rskey=02OIvf&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid).

Comment: @WBT Then allow me to introduce you to the OED, cited in WS2's answer.

Comment: The article does not say that "forty" *started out* as an indefinite number. The English word "forty" is etymologically derived from parts that mean "four" and "ten": it's meant the product of these two numbers from the beginning. The article says that historically the specific number "forty" has been used to express a large indefinite number.

Answer (score 8):

**According to the OED it is *a very large but indefinite number*, clearly, from the examples, of WW2 vintage.**

> Etymology:  < Z n. + million adj. and n.
>
> slang (chiefly U.S.).
>        A very large but indefinite number.
>
> 1944   D. Runyon Runyon à la Carte (1946) 165,   I love him a zillion
>   dollars' worth.
>
> 1947   Esquire May 40/2   Faithful to their zillions of fans.
>
> 1976   National Observer (U.S.)  10 Jan. 10/4   A zillion or so years
>   ago, while I was a student nurse.
>
> 1976   J. Crosby Snake (1977) xvii. 93   She was going to break the
>   story to her zillion readers.
>
> 1983   Sunday Tel. 9 Oct. 20/2   Broken Hill Proprietary..is
>   Australia's biggest company and a zillion times bigger than his own.
>
> 1984   Guardian 29 Oct. 9/2   The whiff of news managers at work,
>   rather than an urge to hear about British Telecom's zillion-pound
>   share sale from the horse's mouth, took me to BT's big press
>   conference on Friday.

Answer (score -3):

This one comes from SpaceX's [JCSAT-14 launch hosted webcast](https://youtu.be/L0bMeDj76ig?t=49m11s), where the "geostationary distance" (distance to [geostationary orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit)) [is defined to be](https://youtu.be/L0bMeDj76ig?t=49m11s) "2.3 ZILLION km:"

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geostationary_orbit), even talking specifically about broadcast and relay communications satellites like the one SpaceX is launching here, cites this known distance as 35,786 km.
Dividing both by 1 km to cancel units, if 2.3 zillion = 35,786, then 1 zillion = 35,786/2.3 = **15,559**.

It's not as high a number as I thought it would be, and is even *less* than a million.

However, this *is* from an expert source known for being precise in the information they plan and give (e.g. see telemetry in upper right corner), and the space industry is about the only one with a practical need for a "zillion km" unit so they should be able to know what it means and/or define it.

Considering context, it's easier to believe that somebody can accurately print a distance on an animation, than to believe that somebody can boost a rocket up towards geostationary orbit and, after a mostly ballistic trajectory peaking ~200km in altitude, slam on the brakes to vertically land a 230' tall burning structure on an autonomous drone ship way out at sea. If one believes that they [pulled off the latter](https://youtu.be/L0bMeDj76ig?t=28m8s) in the same context, one would logically conclude that the animation label, which is much easier to do accurately, is also accurate.

---

*Please take this answer with the same grain of salt you'd apply to that webcast. :-)*

Comment: Do the folks who downvoted anyway think this is not a source that should know what they're talking about when using the term?  (Are the last two paragraphs not helpful on that?)  I didn't edit the image or anything like that, linked to original sources, and explained each step of the math

Comment: My guess is that this source is not *material* to interpreting or defining a zillion, and likely that the webcast was using it *jocularly* (i.e. definitively *not* trying to define "zillion" seriously, or with any kind of precision). The word *zillion* is intentionally, deliberately indefinite: it's a way of saying a "whole lot" (see [my anecdote about using `z`](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324170/how-many-is-a-zillion/324171?#comment737605_324170) [the last letter of the alphabet] as a superlative prefix), and trying to pin it down or quantify it *defeats that purpose*.

Comment: @DanBron "2.3" is inconsistent with "intentionally, deliberately indefinite."

Comment: Yes, that's the point: it was a *joke*.  Hence "jocular".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39476/discussion-on-answer-by-wbt-how-many-is-a-zillion).